# How can I stop triggering click event after the first trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using a triggered click on my website (Its not on the website not due to the bug).

Website: 3six-d.co.uk

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('a[href$="#about"]').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

However as you could possible guess, that works fine. Until someone click the Enter button faster than 5 seconds, and they goes to a different tab. Say I clicked enter then went to the contact form. After the 5 seconds it would then redirect me back to about us. If there a way that if the user has already clicked enter it stops the trigger?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, it's called `clearTimeout` ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with .js , just HTML and CSS, so I'm just not really sure how to implement it :/

Comment: Why are you forcing people to the about page after 5 seconds? Let them navigate themselves.

Comment: Its a request, not a personal decision. :/

Comment: Have you already tried @confile 's suggestion?

Comment: I didnt think he understood me correctly, as there was nothing to link it to pressing the Enter button itself

Comment: @RamisWachtler I tried his suggestion, you can check it on the website now, still not working :(, still takes you to the about if youve already pressed Enter

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var isClicked = false;
setTimeout(function() {
    if (!isClicked) {
      isClicked = true;
      $('a[href$="#about"]').trigger('click');
    }
}, 5000);
```

With the former approach you guarantee that the click is only triggered once. No matter how often the user clicks.

Answer (score 0):

How about a global Boolean variable that is set to true once the trigger is clicked? If the global Boolean is true, it does not allow the trigger event to run again. And, when the global is set to true, another timer is started that resets it to false after five or six seconds?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you mean, but of a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Detect when a user click the "Enter" button (look this up, its easy) then clear the timeouts using:

```
var id = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 0);

while (id--) {
    window.clearTimeout(id);
}
```

Comment: Before I saw your post I had already tried using an 'onclick' to load a function to clearTimeout. However it seemed to do nothing

Comment: Post the code you tried please, my code snippet works 100% (I use it myself to clear timeouts). Your "onlcick" method must have been wrong.

Comment: I've put it here so you can read it all: http://pastebin.com/8DEzvCqe  Thanks for your help! I'm sorry, I'm probably just making a stupid mistake, just not that familiar.

Comment: Well, the myStopFunction() is currently undefined, so that's not going to help!

Comment: try trigger the clearTimeout code using $(document).on('click', '<SELECTOR>', function() { <CLEARTIMEOUT CODE HERE> });

Comment: Ergh, I feel like an idiot, its like you're speaking a different language :/

Comment: Simply jQuery lol. Tbh, the best solution would be to remove the automatic navigation entirely. If it's for a client, explain to them it's not really accepted to force things on the end user. It makes the splash page pretty redundant. Use it instead, put a mission statement or testimonial on there.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Please mark which ever answer you used.

Comment: I didn't in the end :(